# Am i calculating gas the right way?

Tags: solidity

I have a very big smart contract, and i deployed it to mainnet. This contract has a function that swaps some tokens and then returns the profit to the owner, I tested it on REMIX where i saw in the transaction details that the gas used for the transaction was about 3000000[image]

So i did this math to calculate the transaction const in eth: `gasCostInGwei = safeGasPrice (43 gwei) * smartContractGas (3000000 gas);`
And by doing this math i calculated that i needed around 220$ to execute this transaction, but when i try to execute it it reverts with this message:

```
Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS ] (error={"code":-32000,"response":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":9,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"insufficient funds for gas * price + value\"}}"}
```

The thing is that i have the money that i needed for the transaction in my wallet (I have about 0.1327 eth). **And so my question was, Am I calculating gas price in the wrong way?**

**The full contract code:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

// 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D, 0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F
// 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2, 0xc00e94Cb662C3520282E6f5717214004A7f26888, 10000000000000000000, false

interface Structs {
    struct Val {
        uint256 value;
    }

    enum ActionType {
        Deposit, // supply tokens
        Withdraw, // borrow tokens
        Transfer, // transfer balance between accounts
        Buy, // buy an amount of some token (externally)
        Sell, // sell an amount of some token (externally)
        Trade, // trade tokens against another account
        Liquidate, // liquidate an undercollateralized or expiring account
        Vaporize, // use excess tokens to zero-out a c xwompletely negative account
        Call // send arbitrary data to an address
    }

    enum AssetDenomination {
        Wei // the amount is denominated in wei
    }

    enum AssetReference {
        Delta // the amount is given as a delta from the current value
    }

    struct AssetAmount {
        bool sign; // true if positive
        AssetDenomination denomination;
        AssetReference ref;
        uint256 value;
    }

    struct ActionArgs {
        ActionType actionType;
        uint256 accountId;
        AssetAmount amount;
        uint256 primaryMarketId;
        uint256 secondaryMarketId;
        address otherAddress;
        uint256 otherAccountId;
        bytes data;
    }

    struct Info {
        address owner; // The address that owns the account
        uint256 number; // A nonce that allows a single address to control many accounts
    }

    struct Wei {
        bool sign; // true if positive
        uint256 value;
    }
}

abstract contract DyDxPool is Structs {
    function getAccountWei(Info memory account, uint256 marketId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        returns (Wei memory);

    function operate(Info[] memory, ActionArgs[] memory) public virtual;
}

contract DyDxFlashLoan is Structs {
    DyDxPool pool = DyDxPool(0x1E0447b19BB6EcFdAe1e4AE1694b0C3659614e4e);

    address public WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    mapping(address => uint256) public currencies;

    constructor() {
        currencies[WETH] = 1;
    }

    modifier onlyPool() {
        require(
            msg.sender == address(pool),
            "FlashLoan: could be called by DyDx pool only"
        );
        _;
    }

    function tokenToMarketId(address token) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 marketId = currencies[token];
        require(marketId != 0, "FlashLoan: Unsupported token");
        return marketId - 1;
    }

    // the DyDx will call `callFunction(address sender, Info memory accountInfo, bytes memory data) public` after during `operate` call
    function flashloan(
        address token,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes memory data
    ) internal {
        IERC20(token).approve(address(pool), amount + 2);
        Info[] memory infos = new Info[](1);
        ActionArgs[] memory args = new ActionArgs[](3);

        infos[0] = Info(address(this), 0);

        AssetAmount memory wamt = AssetAmount(
            false,
            AssetDenomination.Wei,
            AssetReference.Delta,
            amount
        );
        ActionArgs memory withdraw;
        withdraw.actionType = ActionType.Withdraw;
        withdraw.accountId = 0;
        withdraw.amount = wamt;
        withdraw.primaryMarketId = tokenToMarketId(token);
        withdraw.otherAddress = address(this);

        args[0] = withdraw;

        ActionArgs memory call;
        call.actionType = ActionType.Call;
        call.accountId = 0;
        call.otherAddress = address(this);
        call.data = data;

        args[1] = call;

        ActionArgs memory deposit;
        AssetAmount memory damt = AssetAmount(
            true,
            AssetDenomination.Wei,
            AssetReference.Delta,
            amount + 2
        );
        deposit.actionType = ActionType.Deposit;
        deposit.accountId = 0;
        deposit.amount = damt;
        deposit.primaryMarketId = tokenToMarketId(token);
        deposit.otherAddress = address(this);

        args[2] = deposit;

        pool.operate(infos, args);
    }
}

contract Arbitrage is DyDxFlashLoan {
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uRouter;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable sRouter;

    address public owner;

    constructor(address _uRouter, address _sRouter) {
        uRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uRouter);
        sRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_sRouter);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function executeTrade(
        address _tokenA,
        address _tokenB,
        uint256 _flashAmount,
        bool _startOnUniswap
    ) external {
        console.log("Balance before", IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this)));
        uint balanceBefore = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(
            _startOnUniswap,
            _tokenA,
            _tokenB,
            _flashAmount,
            balanceBefore
        );
        flashloan(_tokenA, _flashAmount, data);
    }

    function callFunction(
        address,
        Info calldata,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external onlyPool {
        (
            bool _startOnUniswap,
            address _tokenA,
            address _tokenB,
            uint256 flashAmount,
            uint256 balanceBefore
        ) = abi.decode(data, (bool, address, address, uint256, uint256));

        console.log("Balance after:", IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this)));
        uint balanceAfter = IERC20(_tokenA).balanceOf(address(this));

        require(
            balanceAfter - balanceBefore == flashAmount,
            "Didn't receive flash loan"
        );

        address[] memory tokens = new address[](2);

        tokens[0] = _tokenA;
        tokens[1] = _tokenB;

        if (_startOnUniswap == true) {
            swapOnUniswap(flashAmount, 0, tokens);

            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            swapOnSushiswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                0,
                tokens
            );
        } else {
            // console.log("Ho 10 WETH e li swappo per x COMPOUND");
            console.log(
                "Balance of WETH before swap:",
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this))
            );
            swapOnSushiswap(flashAmount, 0, tokens);
            tokens[0] = _tokenB;
            tokens[1] = _tokenA;

            // console.log("Ho x COMPOUND e li swappo per >10 WETH");
            swapOnUniswap(
                IERC20(tokens[0]).balanceOf(address(this)),
                0,
                tokens
            );
            console.log(
                "Balance of WETH after swap:",
                IERC20(tokens[1]).balanceOf(address(this))
            );
        }
    }

    function swapOnUniswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(uRouter), _amountIn),
            "Uniswap failed the approval"
        );

        uint[] memory amounts = uRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );

        console.log(
            "UNISWAP: Input tokens (COMP):",
            amounts[0],
            "Output tokens (ETH):",
            amounts[1]
        );
    }

    function swapOnSushiswap(
        uint _amountIn,
        uint _amountOut,
        address[] memory _path
    ) internal {
        require(
            IERC20(_path[0]).approve(address(sRouter), _amountIn),
            "Sushiswap failed the approval"
        );

        uint[] memory amounts = sRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _amountOut,
            _path,
            address(this),
            (block.timestamp + 1200)
        );

        console.log(
            "SUSHISWAP: Input tokens (ETH):",
            amounts[0],
            "Output tokens (COMP):",
            amounts[1]
        );
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external {
        console.log("Owner balance:", IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(owner));
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Only owner can withdraw");
        ERC20(_tokenAddress).transfer(
            owner,
            IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this))
        );
        console.log("Owner balance", IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(owner));
    }
}
```

**How i execute the transaction:**

```
  const options = {
    gasLimit: 3000000,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: 1500000000,
    maxFeePerGas: 77681214788,
  };

  const trade = await arbitrageContract
    .connect(address)
    .executeTrade(
      process.env.TOKEN_WETH_MAINNET,
      process.env.TOKEN_COMPOUND_MAINNET,
      ethers.BigNumber.from("10000000000000000000"),
      startOnUniswap,
      options
    );

  receipt = await trade.wait();
  console.log("sending eth to contract...");
  const withdraw = await arbitrageContract
    .connect(address)
    .withdraw(process.env.TOKEN_WETH_MAINNET);
  await withdraw.wait();
  console.log("sent eth to owner successfully");
```

If you have any suggestion please let me know because it would be very helpful.

Comment: Try to estimate the gas for your transaction to get the actual cost.

Comment: I think that im already doing that, but maybe im wrong, could you show me the code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the transaction will not cost the amount of gas calculated and provided in your options. The RPC will use these settings to calculate the gas your about to spend and check your balance.

The behaviour will vary from one chain to another but general rule is that your account must have the gas it's about to spend.

In your case

You have a balance of: 0.132700000000000000

You are willing to spend 3 000 000 units of gas at a max price of: 77681214788

3000000 * 77681214788 = 233043644364000000 or 0.23304

Which is greater than your balance.

One option would be to get the estimated gas and verify that the transaction really needs 3000000 units of gas.

This value is most likely set in the remix. You can lower to what you need.

[image]

Now how do you figure out what you need in remix??

Go under the settings. And check the option like below, you should see the gas cost in unit next to your function

[image]

It is also good to note that you will never overspend in terms of gas units. If you provide more units than needed you will get refunded. The gas price is what will be spent. Or in your case, The MaxFeePerGas

Comment: thank you really much this solved my problem

Comment: when i activate display gas estimates in editor next to my function there is "infinite gas" or "undefined gas" what does this mean?

Comment: It's possible that remix have a limit to what it can calculate. To get accurate estimate you can use ethers with nodejs or hardhat/truffle.